# Incorrect margins with Res.cls trying to improve spacing

Tags: margins, cv, resume

I know the res class is now considered ***obsolete***, but I can't help myself. I don't like ModernCV's aesthetic, and I couldn't find any comparable alternatives. Michael DeCorte's design is simplistic and traditional. A quick search shows there are still some people that agree.

So, I have made all the proper adjustments, added some custom lists, and specified my paper width and height, but I can't help but notice that there is still some white space at the bottom of the document. The margins don't appear evenly spaced. I have reduced my CV to only the essentials. I cannot remove any more information, but I want more space between everything. I feel the lists need more spacing as well as the labels on the left margin. Is there room in the margins that I can utilize? What can I do to get better spacing? Thank you!!

Here is the res.cls file I'm using:

https://gist.github.com/89sundown/a2ca5aa0e480f45216872a30aabf970f

Here is the LaTeX:

```
\documentclass[margin,line]{res}

\topmargin=-.5in
\oddsidemargin -.5in
\evensidemargin -.5in
\textwidth=6.0in
\itemsep=1in
\parsep=0in
%if using pdflatex:
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{\paperwidth}
\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{\paperheight}

\newenvironment{list1}{
  \begin{list}{\ding{113}}{%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{0in}
      \setlength{\parsep}{0in} \setlength{\parskip}{0in}
      \setlength{\topsep}{0in} \setlength{\partopsep}{0in}
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.15in}}}{\end{list}}
\newenvironment{list2}{
  \begin{list}{$\bullet$}{%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{0in}
      \setlength{\parsep}{0in} \setlength{\parskip}{0in}
      \setlength{\topsep}{0in} \setlength{\partopsep}{0in}
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.2in}}}{\end{list}}
\newenvironment{list3}{
  \begin{list}{$\bullet$}{%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{0.02in}
      \setlength{\parsep}{0in} \setlength{\parskip}{0in}
      \setlength{\topsep}{0in} \setlength{\partopsep}{0in}
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{0in}}}{\end{list}}

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{document}

\name{Xxx x. Xxxxx \vspace*{.05in}}

\begin{resume}
\vspace{-.2cm}
\section{\sc {\bf Contact Information}}
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{2in}p{4in}}
Address xxxxxx             & {\it Voice:}  (xxx) xxx-xxxx \\
Xxxxxxx, XX  XXXXX US   & {\it E-mail:}  x@email $\vert$ xxxx@xxx.edu\\
\end{tabular}

\vspace{-.35cm}
\section{\sc {\bf Professional Aspirations}}
Obtain a Ph.D. in Computational Mathematics, develop specialized knowledge, contribute to ongoing research, and be well-regarded within the scientific community.
\vspace{-.35cm}
\section{\sc {\bf Education}}
\begin{list3}
\item[]{\bf A University}, State, Country USA
\item[]Associates of Science in Mathematics \hfill May Xxxx
\item[]G.P.A 4.0 $\vert$ Xxxxxx College $\vert$ Xxxxx Scholar
\item[]President's List: Xxxxx - Xxxxxx
\item[]Bachelors of Science in Mathematics \hfill May Xxxx
\end{list3}



%\begin{list1}
%\item[] Associate of Science in Mathematics
%\end{list1}
%\begin{list2}
%\vspace*{.05in}
%\item[] Pending Fall 2023 applications of acceptance to Georgia Tech
%\end{list2}
%\vspace*{.05in}
%\item[] Enrolled in BA in mathematics at Georgia State University Graduation May 2025
%\end{list1}
\vspace{-.35cm}
\section{\sc {\bf Honors and Awards}}

\begin{list3}
\item[] {\it X.X.X.X. Award: Mathematics} \hfill  Spring 2022
\item[] {\it A wonderful Scholarship} \hfill Spring 2023
\item[] {\it A wonderful Scholarship} \hfill Spring 2023
\item[] {\it A very wonderful Scholarship Nominee} \hfill  Pending award Mar 2023
\end{list3}
\vspace{-.35cm}
\section{\sc {\bf Research Experience}}


{\em {\bf Xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx (R.E.U.)}} \hfill  Aug 2022 - present\\
One of seven students selected to participate in a paid R.E.U. program over a two-semester period funded by a grant.
% When I entered the program, I came with a question in mind that I wanted to explore in game theory.
\vspace*{.04in}
\begin{list1}
\item[] {\bf Presentations}
\begin{list2}
\item XXXXX, Xxx. 2022. ``XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'' Talk presented at the X. XXXXXXXXX, XXXXXX XXXX XXXXX, November 29
\item XXXXX, Xxx. 2023. ``XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'' Talk presented at the XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX on Undergraduate Mathematics and Statistics Research, II. XXXXXXX XXXXXXXX of XXXXXX, XXXXXXX, XXXX
\end{list2}
\end{list1}
\vspace*{.04in}
\begin{list1}
\item[] {\bf Skills Acquired}: Zotero, Obsidian, Visio, data management \& visaulization, independent study, mathematical communication, manuscript writing.
\end{list1}

\vspace{-.35cm}

{\em {\bf XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}} \hfill  Jun 2022 - Aug 2022\\ %italizize the header
One of 14 students participating in the Math Path program, a paid six-week summer research program funded by the XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.
\vspace*{.04in}
\begin{list1}
\item[] {\bf Presentations} %remove the first person pronouns
\begin{list2}
\item Xxxxx, Xxx, Xxxxx Xxxxx, Xxxxx Xxxxx, and Xxxx Xxxx. 2022. ``XXxxxXXXXXXXXXXX'' Poster xxxx Presentation presented at the most wonderful xxxx  symposium ever at sometime during xxxx the summer.
\end{list2}
\vspace*{.04in}
\end{list1}
\begin{list1}
\item[] {\bf Skills Acquired}: Mathematica, Python, programming logic, graph \& game theory, induction, poster creation, team research \& communication, \LaTeX \, \& Beamer.
\end{list1}
\vspace{-.35cm}

{\em {\bf XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}} \hfill May 2022\\
This program was a paid three-week program funded by a XXXX XXXXX XXXXX XXXX XXX. The focus of the program was to teach students the fundamentals of research.
\vspace*{.04in}
\begin{list1}
\item[] {\bf Skills Acquired}: Research methodology, data analysis, literature review, presentation design.
\end{list1}
\vspace{-.35cm}


\section{\sc {\bf Academic Experience \& Other Activies}}


{\em {\bf XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}} \hfill Jan 2022 - present\\
Hold weekly sessions to support students in Calculus 2 and Discrete Mathematics, develop lesson plans based on the professor's weekly material, and participate in classes to build relationships.
\vspace{-.35cm}

{\em {\bf XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}} \hfill Aug 2022 - Present\\
Xxxxx is a monthly undergrad math research seminar, led by students. Duties involve organizing presenters, reaching out to partner universities, and promoting community growth.
\vspace{-.35cm}

\section{\sc {\bf Professional Experience}}

\begin{list3}
\item[] {\em {\bf Project Manager}, {\it Xxxx Xxxxx Xxxx Xxx.}} \hfill  Xxxxx, XX – 2018 – 2020
\item[] {\em {\bf Operations Manager}, {\it Xxxxxxxx, Xxx}} \hfill  Xxxxx, XX – 2018 – 2020
\item[] {\em {\bf Project Manager}, {\it Xxx Xxx Xxxxxx, Xxxx}} \hfill Xxxxxx, XX – 2015 – 2018
\item[] {\em {\bf Project Manager}, {\it Xxxxx Xxxx. Xx. Xxx}} \hfill Xxxxxx, XX – 2010 – 2015
\end{list3}

\vspace{-.3cm}

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why `\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{\paperwidth}
\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{\paperheight}
\paperwidth=8.5in
\paperheight=11in` ??? You set the pdf media size to match latex's page size then immediately change the latex page size so the pdf is wrong again

Comment: I found this template online and was trying to play around with the recommendations to see if I could get the correct margins. If you notice, there is a comment above that says ``%if using pdflatex``. Those were also commented out, but I was just trying something. Honestly, I didn't understand the correct latex to use.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I updated the document rebuilt the document and nothing changed.